# Doctrine not saving column after join relationship was added

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm using doctrine and I added a join to an entity. After the join a setter (setcustomerorderID) is no longer being saved when they data is saved to the database. Every other column gets saved. The join is correct and $this->data->orderId is set.

The code works without the join.

I added the relationship as follows:

```
/**
 * @var orders
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FYP\CartBundle\Entity\Orders", inversedBy="CustomerDesign")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customerorder_id", referencedColumnName="orderID")
 */
private $orders;
```

On the reverse side:

```
/**
 * @var customerDesign
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FYP\BaseDesignBundle\Entity\CustomerDesign", mappedBy="orders")
 */
private $customerDesign;
```

Attempting to set customerorder_id in a different file.

```
 $cd = new CustomerDesign();
 $cd->setcustomerID($this->data->customerId);
 $cd->setcustomerorderID($this->data->orderId); 
 $cd->setQuantity($cartItem->getQuantity());
 $cd->setProductVariant($cartItem->getProductVariant());
 $cd->setDesignData($cartItem->getDesignData());
 $cd->setRequestProof($cartItem->getRequestProof());
 $cd->setComments($cartItem->getComments());
 $cd->setSpecialComments($cartItem->getSpecialComments());
 $cd->setgiftSetID($cartItem->getgiftSetID());
 $cd->setgiftSetParent($cartItem->getgiftSetParent());
 $cd->setisBlank($cartItem->getisBlank());
 $cd->setbasedOn($cartItem->getbasedOn());
 $cd->setApprovalData($cartItem->getApprovalData());
 $cd->setdesignName('');
 $this->em->persist($cd);
 $this->em->flush();
```

This $cd->setcustomerorderID($this->data->orderId); is not working at all.

setcustomerorderID Looks like:

```
    /**
 * Set customerorder_id
 *
 * @param integer $customerorder_id
 */
public function setcustomerorderID($customerorder_id)
{
    $this->customerorder_id = $customerorder_id;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code here:

```
/**
 * @var order
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FYP\CartBundle\Entity\Orders", inversedBy="CustomerDesign")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customerorder_id", referencedColumnName="orderID")
 */
private $order;
```

As far as I understand, according your relationships, you might have one order to many customer designs.

Instead of ID, you need to assign Entity.

Details can be found in Doctrine documentation.

```
<?php
$order = new Order();
$design = new CustomerDesign();
$design->setOrder($order);
...



public function setOrder($order)
{
    $this->order = $order;
}
...

$this->em->persist($order);
$this->em->persist($design);
$this->em->flush();
```

You created relationships, and it means customerorder_id is under ORM control.

Comment: Thats what I thought the problem was but when I add that I get a 500 error.

Comment: I wrote another example depends on your current relationships

Comment: Ok I got it working without error, but it's still setting the row in the table to null instead of the id.

Comment: For new objects we need to call persist for both main object and related objects.